# angular UI modal backdrop

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am having an issue with an angular ui modal. There is a white rectangle between my modal and the backdrop. Any Ideas?

```
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl:'src/app/shared/confirm-modal.html',
            controller:'ConfirmModalCtrl',
            controllerAs:'vm',
            resolve:{
                data:function(){
                    return {
                        title:'Delete?',
                        message:'Are You Sure',
                        buttons:['OK','Cancel']
                    }
                }
            },
            size:'lg'

        });
        modalInstance.result.then(function(result){
            alert('Ok')
        },function(){
            alert('Canceled')
        });
```

[image: modal]

Comment: Could you post a plunkr or fiddle re-creating this issue? The cause isn't immediately apparent from the code you posted.

Comment: In additional please show you html.

Comment: Could you post a plunkr or fiddle .

Comment: And show your css too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug when using angular-ui-bootstrap 1.13.0 with angular 1.4 due to breaking changes that were made in `$animate` in angular 1.4.

If you set `animate:false` backdrop works but you lose modal animations

You can look through github issue tracker for patches or revert to angular 1.3 until support for angular 1.4 is released

Comment: Thanks. I reverted back to 1.3.

Comment: FYI - there was a new release yesterday but I'm not sure this fix is in it or not. Most likely is since modal is so heavily used